# React router link inside column does not "fill" whole column

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a code like:

```
 <Col lg={2} className={getBgColorBasedOnLocation("/")}>
   <Link to={"/"} className="nav-link"> Url </Link>
 </Col>
```

my problem is that when I go with mouse cursor for example to a corner of this column I can not click it, when I go move cursor closer to the middle / text of url it changes to a link and I can click it.

How to "fill" this link to whole column ? thanks!

Comment: Does your `Col` have padding or margin? If it does have than `Link` will not stretch to corners so you can not click in corners.

Comment: @PriyankKachhela well getBgColorBasedOnLocation adds only background color, so I am not using some extra styles there